# How to access values using multidimensional indices in numpy?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I am having troubles accessing the value from the given indices:

```
indices = array([[[1, 1],
        [1, 2],
        [1, 3],
        [2, 1],
        [2, 2],
        [2, 3],
        [3, 1],
        [3, 2],
        [3, 3]],

       [[1, 2],
        [1, 3],
        [1, 4],
        [2, 2],
        [2, 3],
        [2, 4],
        [3, 2],
        [3, 3],
        [3, 4]],

       [[2, 1],
        [2, 2],
        [2, 3],
        [3, 1],
        [3, 2],
        [3, 3],
        [4, 1],
        [4, 2],
        [4, 3]],

       [[2, 2],
        [2, 3],
        [2, 4],
        [3, 2],
        [3, 3],
        [3, 4],
        [4, 2],
        [4, 3],
        [4, 4]]])
```

for an array:

```
padded_x = array([[0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 1, 1, 0],
       [0, 1, 1, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0]])
```

I tried accessing using `result = padded_x[indices]` but it returns result in shape `(4, 9, 2, 4)`, I need it in shape `(4,9)`.  I do not want to use for loops as I am dealing very large arrays.

Context: The indices represent 3x3 neighbourhood indices at point `[i,j]`. To prevent the out of bounds array access, the original array has been padded (hence the name `padded_x`)

Comment: Unfortunately, the first block of code the lists are missing commas, so we can't create`indices`.

Comment: @gofvonx I just added the commas sorry

Comment: So `indices` is (4,9,2), and you want `indices[:,:,0]` to index the 1st dimension, and `indices[:,:,1]` for the second?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Numpy has some weird indexing rules, when you want to access multiple multi-dimensional indices.

You have to give a tuple containing an iterable for each dimension.
So when you want to access `(0, 0)` and `(2, 3)` of `padded_x`, you'd have to write `padded_x[([0, 2], [0, 3])]`.

For your example, it should be

```
indices = (
    [[-1, -1, -1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1],
     [-1, -1, -1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1],
     [0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2],
     [0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2]],
    [[-1, 0, 1, -1, 0, 1, -1, 0, 1],
     [0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2],
     [-1, 0, 1, -1, 0, 1, -1, 0, 1],
     [0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2]]
)

padded_x = np.array([[0, 0, 0, 0],
                     [0, 1, 1, 0],
                     [0, 1, 1, 0],
                     [0, 0, 0, 0]])

result = padded_x[indices]
```

Notice that the working index array can be created from the indices from your attempt by transposing: `indices = tuple(indices.transpose((2, 0, 1)))`.

It *has* to be a tuple for numpy to regard it as multi-dimensional index! Otherwise it is regarded as a list of 1D indices.

Comment: Apparently there is no need to reshape and you can keep the shape of the index lists inside the tuple, so I removed that part of the answer.